# Entity Framework Database Initialization Seed is not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, dbcontext

I'm using EF Code-First with Identity and I have customized `ApplicationUser` so changed my DbContext and Initializer a little bit.

Having following classes:

```
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MyDbInitializer());
        Database.Initialize(false);
    }
}

public class MyDbInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        // data initialization code here
    }
}
```

In my unit test I create MyDbContext so I expect the Seed method gets called. Note that I don't have migration and this issue is happening in the first run.

The `Seed` method was being called before I inherit `MyDbContext` `IdentityDbContext` instead of `DbContext`. After inheriting from `IdentityDbContext` the `Seed` method is firing anymore.

`ApplicationDbContext` and `IdentityDbContext` are coming from Identity framework

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you replace all usages of `IdentityDbContext` with `MyDbContext`?

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Where should I replace IdfentityDbContext with MyDbcontext? I just call var db = new MyDbContext()

Comment: Have you tried to force DB initialization(`Database.Initialize(true)`)?

Comment: Also I see that you have `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDbContext>`. Should not it be the `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDbContext>`?

Comment: @RomanKoliada, I tried forcing initialize, no luck. But your second guess resolved the issue. Thank you!